# window.name storage for a named window in <=IE7

Tags: javascript

I have an application that uses `window.name` as a fallback storage to `sessionStorage`.

Example (simplified for brevity):

```
function setData(data){
  window.name = JSON.stringify(data);
}
function getData(data){
  return JSON.parse(window.name);
}
```

This all works fine and dandy in just about all browsers. However, I have recently discovered that this DOES NOT work in IE7 and below when the window is launched with a target.

```
<a href="winning.html" target="bob">winning.html</a>
```

If I launch the `winning.html` file from the above `A`, using IE7, `getData` will always return "bob", regardless of what we try to set through `setData`.

If I modify the launch link like so (remove the target), it will set and remember data correctly.

```
<a href="winning.html">winning.html</a>
```

The problem is that I do not always have control of that originating link. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you include the JSON parser in IE7? It's not available in IE7 natively.

Comment: Yes, I am using Crockford's json2.js for <=IE7.

Comment: Doesn't `window.name` only work within a browser window? Wouldn't your page set that value yourself and override the initial value given by the browser?

Comment: That is the point. I am unable to override the value. The value is always "bob".

Comment: This script is not affected by this bug: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

So it must be something I am doing... though I cannot seem to nail down why his works and mine does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, putting this problem down for a couple of days, and then coming back to it fresh has revealed the answer.

I tested the bug using [this script](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/session.js) (from [this Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-session-variable-library/)) for the window.name session storage.

As you might guess, this script is not affected by the bug in my original post. Why? What makes this one work, and my simple example above not work? This bit right here is the key:

```
// page unload event
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("unload", Save, false);
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onunload", Save);
else window.onunload = Save;
```

For some reason, you MUST save the data back into the `window.name` container within the window's `unload` event.

**Beware** of using only the onunload method for this, as mobile safari will not remember the data. To get mobile safari to persist the data in `window.name`, you must save it manually before onunload. Essentially, for maximum compatibility, you must do both: save in onunload; save manually whenever new data is set.

Answer (score -2):

`window.name` probably holds the name of the window which is set when you use `target="bob"`, which actualy is the name of the window or frame ...so just use another global variable for example `window._session` ... if you have frames it would be nice to use `window.top._session`. FYI: All global JS variables are stored in window so if you define a global variable just like that: `var name = "hello"` ... you can access it also as `window.name`

Comment: window.name is a way to remember content after a page has unloaded, the variables you suggest are gone when the page reloads

Comment: ok, you are right, just did't get that it is used as localStorage. may be this page will be helpful [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) ... look for **tested and working even in Internet Explorer 6**

Comment: You should use @ to explain who you're directing your comment to. Right now it looks like you're talking to me, but you should be sending suggestions to @Bart, I'm not the one looking for a fix

Comment: The second part is a helpful hint for @Brat. Anyway, thanks for the note. Can not mention two @'s in a commnent

Comment: The link you sent does not work for all browsers, much less IE <= 7 like the OP mentioned.

Comment: didn't test it but a mozilla developer said the following: "Here is another, less exact, imitation of the localStorage object. It is simpler than the previous one, but it is compatible with old browsers, like Internet Explorer < 8 (tested and working even in Internet Explorer 6). It also makes use of cookies."